# Is there a way that I could build a matrix with the first column and the relationship between columns?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to build a numpy matrix B knowing its first column and the relationships among columns

To be more specific, I have the first column like array([1],[1],[1],[1]) for B , another known matrix A and the relationship is B(t+1)=B(t)+ A(t+1). 
Where B(t) indicates the t column of B. Is there any way that I could build the B using matrix calculation without using for loop?

I have tried np.einsum but it seems like it could only do calculation using the known matrix

A=`matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [2, 4, 5, 6],
          [3, 5, 6, 7],
          [4, 6, 5, 4]])`

B=`matrix([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.]])`

Now, I want to fill the columns of B (except the first column).

I expect the final

B =`matrix([[ 1.,  3.,  6., 10.],
            [ 1.,  5., 10., 16.],
            [ 1.,  6., 12., 19.],
            [ 1.,  7., 12., 16.]])`

Thank you!

Comment: An example might help make this a little more clear.

Comment: It seems like you are throwing away `A[0]`. Because `B[t]` is predefined at `t = 0` When `t=1` `B[1] = B[0]  + A[1]`. Is that what you mean of do you want to include `A[0]`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a new matrix by stacking the first row of `B` and all but the first row of `A`. Then you can use [`np.cumsum()`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to make a cumulative sum:

```
A=np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [2, 4, 5, 6],
          [3, 5, 6, 7],
          [4, 6, 5, 4]])

B=np.matrix([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 0., 0., 0.]])

np.cumsum(np.hstack([B[:,:1], A[:,1:]]), axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
matrix([[ 1.,  3.,  6., 10.],
        [ 1.,  5., 10., 16.],
        [ 1.,  6., 12., 19.],
        [ 1.,  7., 12., 16.]])
```